# template specialization won't compile because it tries to use the base case

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create several template specializations for a template function based upon the type I'm using. For my example I use `float` and `int`. I want to call my function as `fun<float>(args);`. My current implementation looks as follows and is compiled as such `g++ -std=c++20 mve.cpp -o mve`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <float> auto fun() { /*call float c fun */return 0.1;}
template <int> auto fun() { /* call int c fun */ return 1;}

int main(){
  cout << fun<float>() << endl;
}
```

This creates the following error:

```
mve.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mve.cpp:12:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun<float>()’
   12 |   cout << fun<float>() << endl;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~
mve.cpp:7:23: note: candidate: ‘template<float <anonymous> > auto fun()’
    7 | template <float> auto fun() { return 0.1;}
      |                       ^~~
mve.cpp:7:23: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mve.cpp:12:21: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<float <anonymous> > auto fun()’
   12 |   cout << fun<float>() << endl;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~
mve.cpp:12:21: note:   expected a constant of type ‘float’, got ‘float’
mve.cpp:8:21: note: candidate: ‘template<int <anonymous> > auto fun()’
    8 | template <int> auto fun() { return 1;}
      |                     ^~~
mve.cpp:8:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mve.cpp:12:21: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<int <anonymous> > auto fun()’
   12 |   cout << fun<float>() << endl;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~
mve.cpp:12:21: note:   expected a constant of type ‘int’, got ‘float’
```

If I add:

```
template <typename T> T fun() = delete;
```

I get

```
mve.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mve.cpp:12:21: error: use of deleted function ‘T fun() [with T = float]’
   12 |   cout << fun<float>() << endl;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~
mve.cpp:5:25: note: declared here
    5 | template <typename T> T fun() = delete;
      |                         ^~~
```

How can I make it use the specialization for the type I'm giving it? I can't do it the 'normal' implicit way (`template<typename T> fun(T t)`) because I don't have the type that way available at compile time.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for template specialization.  `template <float> auto fun()` should be `template <> float fun<float>()`.  `template<float>` means the template parameter is not a typename at all, it's instead a particular float value.

Comment: And that is assuming you have a `template <typename type_t> type_t func()` which we don't see in your example.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes that works (even with the `= delete`, :'). now the interesting question would be why g++ would accept `template <float> auto fun()` if it were fully wrong. My first guess would be that I'm using another part of the language?

Comment: @TarickWelling It is not wrong at all, it just means something else. It declares a function template `fun` with a non-type template parameter of type `float`. You could call it like this: `fun<1.0f>()`; (In C++20 or later)

Comment: @TarickWelling what do you mean by "fully wrong"?  See the second sentence in my first comment.

Comment: fully understand it now. thanks! Sorry for the confused comments, when a correct answer comes, excitement clouds the mind sometimes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
template <float> auto fun();
```

Declares a function template with an unnamed `float` non-type template argument. You can call it like this `fun<3.1>();`. However this is not what you want.

First you need to declare the template:

```
template <typename T> T fun();
```

Then you can specialize it

```
template <> float fun<float>() { /*call float c fun */return 0.1;}
template <> int fun<int>() { /* call int c fun */ return 1;}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/be8xErha1)

Comment: It is allowed in C++20 (for whatever reason)

Comment: @chrysante why should it not be allowed?

Comment: I struggle to think of an actual use case, because of the comparison/inaccuracy issues with floats.

Comment: @chrysante I can think of many use cases. Something along the line of this https://godbolt.org/z/fY4bna1sG and much more. From the pov of metaprogramming it was an arbitrary resitriction to disallow floating point values.